# NuGet package restore doesn't install packages for asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I have a solution and this solution contains a asp.net web site (not application).

I want to enable C# 6, so have to install nuget packages. I did this in Visual Studio 2015, it creates C:\solution\website\packages.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

I want to follow the best practice that do not add the package binaries into version control system, so I only committed packages.config.

It seems automatic package restore doesn't work for web sites, so I plan to write a svn update script, that whenever I run svn update, the script will run to restore packages in case other developers ran svn clean that deletes unversioned files.

In the script I write

```
nuget.exe restore C:\solution\Website\ -PackagesDirectory C:\solution\packages
```

the command does download missing packages, but it doesn't install the packages.

Does anyone know why? Am I missing anything?

Comment: did you build the solution after downloading packages?

Comment: @Webruster Yes I did. Why?

Answer (score 4):

For *NuGet 2.7+:* Downloads and installs any packages missing from the packages folder.

## Restore packages for a solution file

```
nuget restore a.sln
```

## Restore packages for a solution file, using MSBuild version 14.0 to load the solution and its project(s)

```
nuget restore a.sln -MSBuildVersion 14
```

## Restore packages for a project's packages.config file, with the packages folder at the parent

```
nuget restore proj1\packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\packages
```

## Restore packages for the solution in the current folder, specifying package sources

```
nuget restore -source "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2;https://www.myget.org/F/nuget"
```

For [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#restore)

Comment: @LoveRight you need to tel me /, where is your packages folder in `current` or in `parent`?

Comment: I have the same problem with nuget and a web site.  When I run any of the above `nuget restore` commands, I'm told "All packages listed in packages.config are already installed."  But it isn't true.  I expect the packages to appear in a `Bin` folder beneath my solution, but the folder doesn't even exist.  What now?  I notice that a `packages` folder *does* exist, and it does contain what it should...but I should not be required to manually copy these files into the Bin folder where they belong.  If I install a new package through package manager, it correctly adds to the Bin folder.